# What is the correct order to read/watch Firefly/Serenity?

Tags: suggested-order, firefly, serenity

I have discovered today that there are Serenity books and comics.
I have already seen the series and the movie.

- Books
- Comics
- Series
- Movie

**What is the correct order to read the full material?**

Comment: I think since you watched the show and movie first, you were watching correctly in terms of avoiding spoilers, as the written canon is mostly backstory or side stories. To watch/read them all in canon-chronological order though, check out [this link](http://slayaliveforums.proboards.com/thread/8000/firefly-serenity-canon-chronological-order). There may be tiny inconsistencies that im not aware of though, so ill leave it to someone else to give a more authoritative answer.

Answer (score 19):

As usual, my opinion is always that creator's chosen publication order is the best order to watch/read anything. That would mean:

- All *Firefly* episodes (if possible, the "right" order, which I think is mostly how they come these days)
- *Serenity*
- The comics in publication order.

(I don't know of any *books* about *Serenity* off-hand, but the comics have been collected into single-issue graphic novels; is that what you're thinking about?)

However, if you want to read them in chronological order, it's a bit trickier:

- First, all episodes of *Firefly* in correct Whedon order.
- *Serenity: Better Days*
- *Serenity: Those Left Behind*
- *Serenity: The Other Half*
- *Serenity: Downtime*

  - These last two don't have a definitive place in the timeline, but they occur sometime after the last episode and before the movie (e.g. Inara's still there but River's becoming bad-ass)
- *Serenity*, the movie
- *Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale*

  - This is actually a flashback that takes place *mostly* before any of the other stories, except that it starts with a pivotal scene from the movie before flashing back, so save it till here.
- *Serenity: Float Out*
- *Serenity: It's Never Easy*
- *Serenity: Leaves on the Wind*
- *Serenity: No Power in the 'Verse*